# NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef - Angular 6

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, datasource

I am trying to bind data to the table. Some data has been defined in my component. Data has been provided to the datasource (elements). Within the markup there is the *ngFor which I know works to populate a list. But still I am getting an error, not will the html render. I have followed the example of Angular Material design website with some adjustments that I thought would work.

NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!

```
    <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z0">
  <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="elements">

    <!--POSITION COLUMN-------------------------------------------------->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements" matColumnDef="hangul">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderRowDef> Hangul </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element of elements">{{element.hangul}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!--NAME COLUMN-------------------------------------------------------->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements" matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderRowDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element of elements">{{element.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!--CHARACTERS COLUMN-------------------------------------------------------->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements" matColumnDef="character">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Character </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element of elements">{{element.character}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!--SOUND COLUMN-------------------------------------------------------->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements" matColumnDef="sound">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sound </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element of elements">{{element.sound}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!--TYPE COLUMN-------------------------------------------------------->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements" matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element of elements">{{element.type}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My html formatting for the tables where the data will be rendered.

```
import {Component, } from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from "@angular/cdk/collections";

/*
* ALPHABET COMPONENT MODULE
* CONSISTS OF DATA ELEMENTS AND ATTRIBUTES
*
* */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hangul-alphabet',
  templateUrl: './hangul-alphabet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hangul-alphabet.component.scss']
})

export class HangulAlphabetComponent {



  displayedColumns = ['hangul', 'name', 'character', "sound",'type'];
  elements = ELEMENT_DATA;



  ngOnInit() {

  }

}


export interface Element {
  hangul    : number;
  name      : string;
  character : string;
  sound     : string;
  type      : string;
}


const  ELEMENT_DATA : Element[] = [
  {hangul : 1,  name: 'giyeok'      , character : 'ㄱ', sound : 'g,k'  ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 2,  name: 'nieun'       , character : 'ㄴ', sound : 'n'    ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 3,  name: 'digeut'      , character : 'ㄷ', sound : 'd,t'  ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 4,  name: 'rieul'       , character : 'ㄹ', sound : 'l,r'  ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 5,  name: 'mieum'       , character : 'ㅁ', sound : 'm'    ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 6,  name: 'bieup'       , character : 'ㅂ', sound : 'b,p'  ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 7,  name: 'shiot'       , character : 'ㅅ', sound : 's'    ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 8,  name: 'leung'       , character : 'ㅇ', sound : 'ng'   ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 9,  name: 'jieut'       , character : 'ㅈ', sound : 'j,ch' ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 10, name: 'chieut'      , character : 'ㅊ', sound : 'ch'   ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 11, name: 'kiuek'       , character : 'ㅋ', sound : 'k'    ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 12, name: 'tieut'       , character : 'ㅌ', sound : 't'    ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 13, name: 'pieup'       , character : 'ㅍ', sound : 'p'    ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 14, name: 'hieutk'      , character : 'ㅎ', sound : 'h'    ,type: "consonant"},
  {hangul : 15, name: 'a'           , character : 'ㅏ', sound : 'a'    ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 16, name: 'ya'          , character : 'ㅑ', sound : 'ya'   ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 17, name: 'o'           , character : 'ㅗ', sound : 'o'    ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 18, name: 'yo'          , character : 'ㅛ', sound : 'yo'   ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 19, name: 'u'           , character : 'ㅜ', sound : 'u'    ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 20, name: 'yu'          , character : 'ㅠ', sound : 'yu'   ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 21, name: 'eu'          , character : 'ㅡ', sound : 'eu'   ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 22, name: 'i'           , character : 'ㅣ', sound : 'i'    ,type: "vowel"},
  {hangul : 23, name: 'ssang gieut' , character : 'ㄲ', sound : 'kk'   ,type: "double consonant"},
  {hangul : 24, name: 'ssang digeut', character : 'ㄸ', sound : 'tt'   ,type: "double consonant"},
  {hangul : 25, name: 'ssang bieup' , character : 'ㅃ', sound : 'pp'   ,type: "double consonant"},
  {hangul : 26, name: 'ssang shiot' , character : 'ㅆ', sound : 'ss'   ,type: "double consonant"},
  {hangul : 27, name: 'ssang jieut' , character : 'ㅉ', sound : 'jj,tch',type:"double consonant"},
  {hangul : 28, name: 'yae'         , character : 'ㅒ', sound : 'yae'  ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 29, name: 'e'           , character : 'ㅔ', sound : 'e'    ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 30, name: 'ye'          , character : 'ㅖ', sound : 'ye'   ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 31, name: 'oe'          , character : 'ㅚ', sound : 'oe'   ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 32, name: 'wae'         , character : 'ㅙ', sound : 'wae'  ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 33, name: 'wi'          , character : 'ㅟ', sound : 'wi'   ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 34, name: 'we'          , character : 'ㅞ', sound : 'we'   ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 35, name: 'ui'          , character : 'ㅢ', sound : 'ui'   ,type: "diphthongs"},
  {hangul : 36, name: 'wo'          , character : 'ㅝ', sound : 'wo'   ,type: "diphthongs"},
];
```

My component file from which I will be rendering the data.

LINK TO STACKBLITZ : https://angular-dtc94b.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about [Angular template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Stars aren't mandatory.

> matCellDef → *matCellDef
>   matHeaderRowDef → *matHeaderRowDef
>   matHeaderCellDef → *matHeaderCellDef
>   matRowDef → *matRowDef

Comment: When I add the ' * ' I get multiple errors stating. [Property binding matCellDefOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations"]

Comment: This is all confusing to me as I thought following the examples would be straight forward.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you followed the example, since you omitted the stars. Now that it doesn't work with the correct syntax, could you make a [mcve] on stackblitz to show the issue ?

Comment: Managed to do as you recommended link to project : https://angular-dtc94b.stackblitz.io

Comment: You know what, it seems you're messing with me. I've looked at your stackblitz and it's literally garbage. So either you follow the example on the site, or you provide a stackblitz that shows your issue, or you find your issue yourself. (By the way, I have found the answer, but I'm not your code monkey).

Comment: Thank you for your effort I am not here to get an easy answer. I've been on this problem for more than 2 days now. And I have tried many methods. It took me and hour just to figure out how to use Stackblitz.I am not looking for someone to solve my problem. Just a point in the right direction.

Comment: Ok then sure : 1. Import the material library correctly 2. read their guide on getting started 3. Follow this guide 4. Copy the example of the table you can find in the documentation 5. replace the name of columns and properties with your own.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I managed to get it to render finally. Though in my Webstorm IDE it still shows text syntax errors within my HTML markup, but no compiling errors.